# Angular factory: return $http promise or data?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-factory, angularjs-http

Pretty new to Angular, what I want to ask is which practice is considered better between

#### Sending promise to the controller

Controller

```
factory.method()
  .success(function (data) {
    // do stuff
  })
  .error(function (data) {
    // throw error
  });
```

Service

```
return {
  method: function() {
    return $http.get(url);
  }
};
```

and

#### Sending data to the controller

Controller

```
myValue = factory.method();
```

Service

```
return $http.get(url).then(function(req){
   return req.data;
});
```

Note that I might be completely off-road here and second method might even not work (haven't tested it yet), but just wanted to ask out of curiosity. If there are better or more effectives practices I would be really glad to hear about them, thank you all very much.

Comment: Check out John Papa's style guide https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Comment: I think the first solution is the best if we just put the business logic in a service. So the service returns a promise when the data has been received and they have been treated if needed.

Comment: I just answered a very similar question: [Angular Best practice: promise in a Factory or in a Controller?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30053875/968155)

Comment: That's similar but not a duplicate. He's asking about a **design** concern, and a realy interesting concern for community. For example angular's [$http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) returns a promise whereas [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) returns a "magic later-populated object". He's just not asking "how to return a promise"... Just not the same question, and not the same answer. See bellow.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use the first solution that I can confirm it works pretty well. Among other things, for example it allows you to :

- **control asynchronous flow** from your controllers
- thus **chain** services, **paralellize** and **join** them, **show spinners** and stuff
- reuse the same services in other asynchronous contexts, such as **routes resolution**
- handle promise **rejection**

---

#### Edit:

That said, in addition, you could do **both**, like [Restangular does](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#enhanced-promises) with "*enhanced promises*". Returning a `then`able thing, with an `$object` or `$return` or whatever attached to it would allow you to :

- Use the promise

  ```
  myService.myMethod.then(
    function(data) {//Success
      //Manipulate data
      $scope.whatever = data;
    },
    function(err) {
      //Handle error
    }
  );
  ```
- Or just the `$return`, that will be populated **later**, when promise resolves

  ```
  $scope.whatever = myService.myMethod().$return;
  //Notice that you just can't handle rejection
  ```

An example of service like that, using angular `$q` service :

```
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  //Create $return reference
  deferred.promise.$return = [];    

  deferred.promise.then(function(data) {
    //replace $return elements with data elements, keeping reference
    angular.copy(data, deferred.promise.$return);
  });

  setTimeout(function() {
    deferred.resolve([
      'White',
      'Pinkman'
    ]);
  }, 1000);

  return deferred.promise;
```

Haven't tested this code, but you get the idea