# Self Populating AngularJS Factories

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-factory

I'm looking for some input on exactly how to accomplish the following design pattern.

Background: I have two factories and a controller:

- `FirstFactory`: This is the data storage that contains all the data the application relies on to function
- `SecondFactory`: This is a list of `$http.get` methods. The `getAllCities` method just returns a promise
- `Controller`: This is where the data resolves from `SecondFactory` and then is set into `FirstFactory.journey`.

Now currently the controller works fine but I am trying to have the data, from `SecondFactory.getAllCities()` resolve itself in the `FirstFactory` on runtime instead of waiting for the `Controller` to update it.

So currently I have a controller that does the following:

```
build = function() {
    return SecondFactory.getAllCities()
        .then(function(response) {
            FirstFactory.journey = response;
        });
};
```

This works fine and updates the factory with a the data returned from the method `SecondFactory.getAllCities()`. However I feel that the controller shouldn't be what sets up the `default` or `init` data set, I think the factory should accomplish this on it's own.

I assumed, probably incorrectly, that the following would work as instead of doing the call to the `SecondFactory` inside the controller, I was just moving this call to the `FirstFactory` so it can resolve itself when its instantiated instead of relying on the controller to populate the `FirstFactory.journey` with data.

```
var build;

//This is a call to a factory that contains the data 
//I want to grab and store this in my factory on run
build = function() {
    SecondFactory.getAllCities()
        .then(function(response) {
            //Why does this not get returned?
            console.log(response);
            return response
        })
};

//This is the factory object that is returned
return {
     journey: build()
}
```

However the above doesn't work. The `console.log` in the build function contains the data I require but it isn't being returned by that function. Is this an issue with my implementation of the promise or a broader design pattern issue?

Comment: First, let's get the terminology right. Angular has services; services are the singleton instances you mentioned. A "factory" is a function that creates a service instance - it's one method of creating a service; `.factory` takes such a function as its 2nd parameter. Another method is via a constructor function - this is done with (unfortunately named) `.service` call. So, now... what exactly is this code supposed to do... Show some concrete example of where the data is populated from, and how it is used

Comment: So are you saying the issue here is that I am trying to do this as a `.factory` as opposed to a `.service`? - Granted the syntax would change a bit, I couldn't just change the definition

Comment: I'm not even close to figuring out what the issue is, since I don't understand what the desired outcome and the context of where this code resides. It also doesn't help when the terminology is all over the place... Remember, we don't have all the of the context that you have. You have something that works, right? Show at least that, and explain what you want changed

Comment: I have updated and fleshed out the question now. I am still confused about why my terminology is incorrect.

Comment: What is `build`? is this supposed to be the data? Because it wouldn't be. The data is retrieved asynchronously, so `build` is a promise of the data. To get the data out of it, do: `build.then(function(d){...})`... You can definitely populate the `FirstFactory` service, but it would initially have undefined values, until the data is retrieved. So, the controller can't quite rely on the data being there. So, if you have an async-retrieved data, you keep the promise-based API throughout your app. Or, you can use `resolve` in `ngRoute` and `ui.router`; this will delay the controller instantiation

Comment: As for the terminology confusion, read the last part of my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30051412/angular-best-practice-promise-in-a-factory-or-in-a-controller/30053875#30053875

Comment: I would assume that if in the controller I was referencing the object, something like `var journey = FirstFactory.journey` then when the factory propagated it would update the controller accordingly. Is this not the case? Is there a way to rewrite the `build` function to not be a promise? `SecondFactory.getAllCities()` is already a promise, as it just returns a `$http.get`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92366/discussion-between-new-dev-and-aleski).